# Please could you explain this regular expression (replaces special characters from a string)?

Tags: java, regex

The following code replaces special characters from a string. For example, "áãç" turns into "aac".

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class Util {
    public static String formatString(String s) { 
        String temp = Normalizer.normalize(s, java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
        return temp.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]",""); 
        }
}
```

But, actually, I didn't understand how it works (I only know that works fine).
Could anyone explain?

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation for [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFD decomposes letters into different code points (for instance, "à" is decomposed into "a, combining acute accent" -- two unicode characters).

The `\p{ASCII}` "class" in Java regexes represents all Unicode characters which are also ASCII characters.

Therefore, the regex will remove all Unicode characters which are *not* ASCII; hence the result.

The [`Normalizer` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) has a better explanation on Unicode {de,}composition.

Answer (score 1):

> \p{ASCII} ==> All ASCII:[\x00-\x7F]

`[\x00-\x7F]` ==> This range is of ascii characters. If any character's ascii value falls in between this range then match is found.

`[^\\p{ASCII}]` ==> If  any character's ascii value does not falls in between this range then match is found.

Check the **POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)** section of [Patter class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the regex is only added to make sure nothing "illegitimate" remains.

The normalizer does the heavy lifting. According to the javadoc, you can check "http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-23.html" for more information regarding the NFD normalization.